How to filter a column when cells are merged together (Filter on Merge Cells In Excel)
When cells are merged, only the merged head cell is displayed at the moment of the filter. I want the head cells to be displayed along with the other cells when filtering
More details in the picture

When the cells are merged together, only the merged head cells will be displayed at the moment of filtering.


It can't be done. A workaround would be to designate a cell for the filter value and use VBA to hide the undesired rows. Or maybe add a helper column with no merged cells and filter on it.

hi @VBasic2008 .What is the shortest possible way to get to the non-merged column? Because I can't manually remove 500 thousand rows of merged cells.


Click the button after filtering

Sub Demo()
    Dim c As Range, r As Range, visRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set visRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not visRng Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In visRng.Cells
            With c.MergeArea
                If .Cells.Count > 1 Then
                    For Each r In .Cells
                        r.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                    Next
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End If
End Sub



The similar idea but a slightly diiferent code.
Sub Demo()
    Dim c As Range, visRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set visRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not visRng Is Nothing Then
        visRng.Select
        For Each c In Selection
            If Intersect(c, visRng) Is Nothing Then _
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Next
    End If
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Item(1).Select
End Sub

And the next possible variant.
Sub Demo1()
    Dim c As Range, visRng As Range, cc As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Set visRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not visRng Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In visRng
            cc = c.MergeArea.Count
            If cc > 1 Then
                c.MergeArea.Cells(2).Resize(cc - 1).Rows.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

